# Speed of people measured by gps

Tags: qgis, data

I was tracking tourist's movement patterns in a city with GPS and I would like to know the speed of all participants (60). The data were recorded and saved in gpx files, so in order to open it and work with it in QGIS, I converted the tracks from gpx to KML and SHP. I would like to know the speed of participants, but the only data I have is a track with points without any information about their speed. I was wondering if there is a program that could calculate and vizualize the speeds.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE Lenka! Perhaps this post might help: [QGIS: Colour GPS track by speed](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68947/qgis-colour-gps-track-by-speed).

Comment: You can view GPX files directly in QGIS without converting them. Have you tried http://www.javawa.nl/analyser_en.html?

Comment: do  you have timestamps for points ?

Comment: @Joseph,thanks, but this is too complicated for me, or it doesn't work for my specific use case, I'm using the egis for the first time

Comment: @Jakob thanks, it looks great. Do you think there is a way to merge the tracks in one and get something like a heat map?

Comment: @simplexio I have timestamps for points but only in gpx files

Comment: What do you mean by merging a track. Convert it to a line for each participants? Can you provide a download link for the GPX file?

Comment: You can determine speed with the formula "speed = distance travelled/Time taken". So if you have the lengths of the track logs and work out time taken from the time stamps, you can calculate the speed.

Comment: @Jakob yes, i would like to convert it to a line for all 60 participants. Maybe you can help me. Here is the link of the gpx tracks https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qqvrkip9w47lk1b/AACdJkaqk_CWbZk6QAmqg28Ka?dl=0

Comment: It look like loading gpx and saving track_points layer doesn't work, it look like it truncated time field. you could try ogr2ogr if it can handle timestamps. Or open gpx in excel( open office probably works too). Let excel figure xml out and copy data what you want to another excel file, save as csv and import to qgis.

Answer (score 3):

Get the track and trackpoints by dragging the GPX file into QGIS. But the time seems wrong. It takes 5 second to walk minimum 48 meters? Shown with the two selected points of the first GPX file.

[image]

How to get to the map image:

- Open the GPX file in QGIS. Drag it to the map or use the Add Vector Layer button.
- Turn off visibility of non track layers. Keeping the track_points and tracks.
- Label the track_points layer with the expression: right(time,8)

Comment: yeah, that is weird, but thank you anyway for trying it out for me...how did you do that? could you maybe write me the steps you have done, so I could try it as well. Thank

Comment: Updated the answer with the steps producing the map.